# Google Play say "You dont have any device"

Tags: google-play-store

I've just bought Ewing I960 android tablet. strangely this device does not come with google play store. So I try to install directly from google play site.
But could not install any of the android apps. Got this message from google when installing the apps. So not apps can be install.

I did download latest google play apk. It got installed but fail when opening the apps.

Hope I can get some light on how to resolve this.
thank you.

ag.

Comment: See if you are logged in with the same Google account that you used on your tablet

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your device is not supported by Google ([list of devices that support Google Play](https://storage.googleapis.com/support-kms-prod/61064765E6620C413FE3010AC51BDFA9098F)). Anyway, you can try to find GApps - Google applications that come pre-installed with most of devices. In your case they must be installed via recovery.